# deleting elements in an array by using a list of indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I have a numerical indexed array of strings. Another array contains a set of index of the first array. I want to delete all the elements in the first array if the index of the first array element is in the second array. How can I do it in php? is there any function for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$strings = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$indexes = array(1, 2);
$strings = array_diff_key($strings, array_flip($indexes));
```